# Traversing and getting values from cl-html5-parser DOM

Tags: html, dom, lisp, common-lisp

So I parsed http://deadgho.st using `cl-html5-parser` and got back the document node. From here, I'm not sure what I need to do to traverse and obtain values from the tree. Originally I was using `cxml-stp` and that had `find-recursively-if`, `local-name`, `attribute-value`, etc functions. I don't know what the equivalent is.

```
(html5-parser:parse-html5 (drakma:http-request "http://deadgho.st"))
```

Comment: Down-vote explanations always appreciated.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but notice that reasons for closing questions include: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."  If you've made an attempt, what was it, and what didn't work about it?  If you haven't, note that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**" You may have made some attempts, but the question as stated now doesn't show it.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the case or not, but this seems like the kind of question that might be answerable based on the documentation (but sometimes documentation is shoddy).  People may downvote that kind of question if it looks like you haven't made an attempt to read the documentation.

Comment: In this case, [the README](https://github.com/copyleft/cl-html5-parser/blob/master/README.asciidoc) says "Parsing HTML5 is not possible without a DOM. cl-html5-parser defines a minimal DOM implementation for this task. Functions for traversing documents are exported by the HTML5-PARSER package." Have you looked at what other functions exported by the HTML5-PARSER package?  The [packages.lisp](https://github.com/copyleft/cl-html5-parser/blob/master/packages.lisp) has a section ";; A simple DOM".  It seems that some utility functions (e.g., `find-recursively-if`) are things you'll have to write.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/thodg/priest/blob/master/priest.lisp